# Find a string in one column if exist than give that value othere wise find in other column in a single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 column in database with 20000 records.

Let take a example

```
id | country_string       |  country_code<br>
275| Bangalore,BLR-India  |  BLR<br>
375| Basongo,BAN          |  BAN
```

I have given one record. I'm searching BLR. First it should match from country_code column if there then it will return the record otherwise it should search in country_string.It should be in single query.

if I'm using LIKE query And I search BAN It will give both record but It should come record number 375 and searching bang it should give record number 275

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `LIKE`.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE country_code LIKE '%BAN%'
OR country_string LIKE '%,BAN%';
```

Comment: @user2980414: Is it same in all the rows that there is a comma before the `country_code` in `country_string`?

Comment: @user2980414: Then you may can add a comma in front of the keyword in `country_string`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I got it dude. I have updated my answer. You just try it and give me the feedback.

Comment: Hey man, you have told you need to search the 3 letter keyword in both the columns and now you are searching with 4 letters. What is this? You have to mention the question properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table where 
country_code like '%$search_name%' 
OR country_string like '%$search_name%'
```

Comment: 375| Basongo,BAN | BAN, I have one more record, As I told It should search in country_code column first. If I'll go with your query and I search BAN it will give both record but in that case I want only Record NO 375.

Comment: @user2980414 you can go with the if condition......if the $search is null in country code the go with the another field search if not execte that query....i hope this will helpfull to you